# Laravel remove first item in a collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to remove the first item in a collection:

```
unset($productData->images->first())
```

The above doesn't work.

The reason I want this is so that later when I do a foreach, the first item doesn't come out:

```
@foreach($productData->images as $images)
    <img class="product-thumb" src="/images/products/{{$images->src_thumb}}">
@endforeach
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `shift()` to get and remove the first item of a Laravel collection.
See the [Source of Illuminate\Support\Collection](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L492)

And here's an example:

```
$productData->images->shift();
```

Comment: The shift method returns that first removed from a collection item. Not the collection.

Comment: After `shift()`, make sure to use `->all();` to get the new result without the first item. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-shift

Answer (score 10):

In Laravel 5 you can use [slice()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-slice) method:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
$slice = $collection->slice(4); 

$slice->all();    // [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 6):

I do:

```
$first_key = $collection->keys()->first();
$collection = $collection->forget($first_key);
```